# IE6 Users must be told to use Firefox

Tags: firefox, internet-explorer-6, requirements

I am working on a site that has to use IE6 !!! BUT also requires intranet users to access apps that need Firefox. Is there a slick way of doing this when launching the app? (link pop up - seems old fashioned). Not sure how much access I have to the root directory, ie for HTaccess

thoughts much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `<div>` element inside [conditional comments](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_comment) and display it for intranet users only based on an IP check.